# First N distinct column values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, if-statement

Goal: extract a `list` of first N distinct values of a column.

Distinct, meaning different from each other but **not unique** to the entire DataFrame.

---

For example, the **first 5 distinct values of col A**.

DataFrame:

```
             A    B    C
0         BERT  foo  bar
1         BERT  foo  bar
2          MLP  foo  bar
3       Albert  foo  bar
4       Albert  foo  bar
5       Albert  foo  bar
6      Roberta  foo  bar
7   Roberta v2  foo  bar
8   Roberta v2  foo  bar
9      BigBird  foo  bar
10      Muppet  foo  bar
```

Desired Output:

```py
top_5 = ['BERT', 'MLP', 'Albert', 'Roberta', 'Roberta v2']
```

Effectively, ignoring duplicates and all other preceding distinct values.

Please let me know if there's anything else I should clarify in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) with select first 5 values and converting to list:

```
first_5_unique = df.A.unique()[:5].tolist()
```

Or use [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) with [`Series.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html):

```
first_5_unique = df.A.drop_duplicates().head().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large dataframe, a very efficient solution is to use a generator with help from `itertools`/[`more_itertools.unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen):

```
# pip install more-itertools
from itertools import islice
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

list(islice(unique_everseen(df['A']), 5))
```

This is several orders of magnitude faster if you are working with thousands of rows as iteration will stop as soon as enough elements are collected (vs reading the whole column with pandas' `unique`)

Comment: In my case, the DataFrame is small. I'll keep this solution noted for future work. Cheers